# Detect changes in component checkbox (ng prime)

Tags: checkbox, angular8, primeng

I have created a table with checkbox components (ng prime components). Does anyone know how I can control the event without changing the value? I have used the Onchange () function 
but was done before changing it so if my condition is successful the value is changed.

`<p-checkbox [(ngModel)]="rowData[col.field]" binary="true" (onChange)="btnComprobarMismoTipo($event, rowData.etiqueta, rowData.tipo)" (change)="btnPrueba()"></p-checkbox>`

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
[ngModel]="rowData[col.field]"
```

instead of 2-ways binding

```
[(ngModel)]="rowData[col.field]"
```

Handle logic in `onChange` event, then change `rowData[col.field]` value if valid condition